# Issue reassigning fields using methods in in the same class

Tags: c++, class

I am developing relatively basic code for molecular dynamics simulations, and I've decided to try and mix in some OOP for the first time. My class `P` contains basic fields (mass, position, and velocity) for particles, and I will generate derived classes for specific potential functions like Lennard-Jones.

I run into an issue with the `setSpecies` function; my goal with it is to be able to pass the chemical formula or name of a species and have the mass automatically set. However, I can't seem to change the value of `m`, aside doing so like where I set it equal to 7:

P.h

```
#ifndef P_H_
#define P_H_
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct P {
    static int N; // total number of particles
    int n; //particle number
    double m; //mass
    void setSpecies(string species);
    P();
};
#endif
```

P.cpp

```
#include "P.h"
#include <algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::algorithm::iequals;
using namespace std;

void P::setSpecies(string species){
    if (boost::iequals(species,"argon") || boost::iequals(species,"Ar")){
        m = 6.6335209e-26; //no good
    }
    else
        m = 0.0; // no good
    //m = 7.0; // this one works when not commented
};

P::P() {
    m = 0.0;
    n = N++;
};
```

Even attempting to reassign the value in main() doesn't do anything:

```
P atom[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        atom[i].setSpecies("Ar"); \\ no good
        atom[i].m = 4.0; \\ no good
    }
```

My guess is it has to do something with the objects being in an array or maybe that I'm using `boost`, but I don't get any compile or runtime errors. What am I missing?

Comment: There are too many variants of your code in one. Extract *one* example where you would expect `m` to be set while it isn't, i.e. a [mcve]. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore your classes and boost your code boils down to:

```
double m;
if (condition){
    m = 6.6335209e-26;
}
else{
    m = 0.0;
}
m = 7.0;
```

No matter what `condition` is, the value set inside your `if` or `else` statements gets overwritten by `m = 7.0`.